# How can i extract for specific set of rows from large set of data to find statistical operations. Each set is incremented by 1 in both sides?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I would like to find some statistical operations such as mean, median, stdev and variance from a large dataset(.mat). Let's say,it contains 1000*1.
*Here, would like to find for each 10 rows find mean and median etc and keep it in a new column. i.e,*

```
1 to 10 rows has mean value is x.
2 to 11 rows has mean then value is x.     
....................................................
...................................................
untill 989 to 999 mean value is x.  
last row(1000) is eleiminated.
```

similarly median,stdev etc these values keep in col1(mean); col2(median) col3(varience) and col4(stdev).
I am able to solve these features for my entire dataset. But here every time the index is incremented by 1 both direction!

should i write mean, median... functions in FOR loop itself or separately. can you give me any example!!!

*This is my code!!! But not has luck in output.*

```
mat1 = scipy.io.loadmat('E:\PythonPr\DeepLearningPr\zerosnmri.mat')     
mat2 = scipy.io.loadmat('E:\PythonPr\DeepLearningPr\zerosnmriattack.mat')  #

#Feature selection
def mean(values):
   length = len(values)
   total_sum = 0
   for i in range(length):
       total_sum += values[i]
   total_sum = sum(values)
  avg = total_sum*1.0/length
  return avg

n = np.mean(mat1)
#print(n)
m = statistics.variance(mat2)
#print(m)

def stanDev (values):
   length = len(values)
   m = mean(values)
   total_sum = 0
   for i in range(length):
       total_sum += (values(i)-m)**2
   under_root = total_sum*1.0/length
```

Already checked in stack portal. But i didn't find incremented in both sides and find these features. Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas comes with rolling statistics out of the box through e.g. [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html); if, for instance, `values` is given by

```
values = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(size=1000))
```

then you can get your four desired collections of statistics by using

```
values.rolling(window=10).agg([np.mean, np.median, np.var, np.std])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. Is it incremented by one in both directions? and should i inculde in for loop ! i am very new to data science.

Comment: The `i`th value of, say, the first column, is the mean of values.`i - 10 + 1` through `i`; try running it on `np.arange(1000)` and check that the results match your expectation.

Comment: Thanks i am getting what i need. But here i have .mat file. i i tried to get with reading mat file by converting the to .csv or txt file but no luck. and also i am getting first 9 values are NONE.

Comment: Those values are NaN because there are not 10 values preceding them so that would be the expected behavior.

Comment: values = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(size=1000)) here 1000 is not fixed. i want to .mat file. first 1 to 20 values are given (51,57,62,66,70,73,76,77,77,76,73,70,66,62,57,0,46,41,36,32....). here the size taken from my mat1 file or it takes random 1000 numbers.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: i have 10,000 values in my dataset (named as mat1). if we write
  
`values = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(size=10000))` 

the out put should read from my dataset. Here, if i increase size = 1,00,000/ or more, then getting output. My question is that, i have only size = 10000(my dataset). if it increases the dataset size values O/P should get error. and also when i calculate mean by myself answer is not correct as o/p appears(here) @fuglede thanks for your help and support. i tried it before asking but it doesn't  get sucess with various functions. sorry for inconvience.